# How does regularized regression overcome the p > n problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, lasso, regularization, elastic-net

So, I understand why simple linear or logistic regression will have infinite solutions in this case (good answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118278/regession-diagnostics) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139353/why-does-logistic-regression-not-work-in-p-n-setting)). But while LASSO will only select n features, Elastic net does not have this limitation. [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274225/why-regularization-shrinkage-method-works-for-pn) explains how regularization limits the potential solutions to a problem so that building a model can be possible. Is the same concept true of Elastic Net? If regularization limits the possible solutions, then how is the "final" solution chosen from that space?

Comment: Have a look at https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/TALKS/enet_talk.pdf

Comment: @GabrielRomon I looked through this but perhaps the section I need went over my head... where in here do they address the problem of selecting more predictors than observations?

Comment: A lot is said on page 9. For the details you definitely want to check [the original paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.124.4696). If something in the paper is unclear, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: With penalization the effective p is much lower than the apparent p.

Comment: Near duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274225/why-regularization-shrinkage-method-works-for-pn#comment1170729_274225.

Answer (score 2):

One way to look at this is that (as long as $\lambda_2\neq 0$) the L2 penalty is equivalent to adding $p$ examples:
$$
\Vert y - X \beta \Vert^2 + \lambda_2 \Vert \beta \Vert^2 =
\Vert \tilde y - \tilde X \beta \Vert^2
$$
with
$$
\tilde X = \begin{bmatrix}X\\ \sqrt{\lambda_2} I_{p\times p}\end{bmatrix} \quad
\tilde y = \begin{bmatrix}y\\ 0_{p\times 1}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So, in general, $n\times p$ ridge regression is equivalent to $(n+p)\times p$ non-regularised regression. Similarly $n\times p$ elastic-net regression is equivalent to $(n+p)\times p$ Lasso regression.