# Generating a full rank model matrix in R

Tags: r, repeated-measures, experiment-design, model, contrasts

For a particular tool I need a model matrix which allows me to build desired contrasts and which is a full rank, i.e. no columns are linear combinations of other columns.

The experimental design involves four factors:

- type (T) with two levels, A and B
- group (G) with two levels, C and T
- time point (TP) with three levels
- subject id (SID)

Both A and B samples were taken from each subject. Subjects either belong to group C or T (control vs treatment). Multiple samples were taken from each subject at different time points.

The comparisons I desire to make are always within a type (no comparisons between types). I want to test interaction between time points and groups, so for example `(T.TP1-C.TP1)-(T.TP0-C.TP0)`.

The only problem is that the model matrix must be full rank, and I don't know how to achieve it.

Here is a mock example:

```
mock <- data.frame(
  ID=paste0("ID", 1:16), 
  type=rep(c("A", "B"), each=8), 
  treatment=rep(c("C", "T"), each=4), 
  tp=c("T1", "T2"), 
  PID=rep(paste0("P.", 1:8), each=2))
```

which gives

```
     ID type treatment tp PID
1   ID1    A         C T1 P.1
2   ID2    A         C T2 P.1
3   ID3    A         C T1 P.2
4   ID4    A         C T2 P.2
5   ID5    A         T T1 P.3
6   ID6    A         T T2 P.3
7   ID7    A         T T1 P.4
8   ID8    A         T T2 P.4
9   ID9    B         C T1 P.5
10 ID10    B         C T2 P.5
11 ID11    B         C T1 P.6
12 ID12    B         C T2 P.6
13 ID13    B         T T1 P.7
14 ID14    B         T T2 P.7
15 ID15    B         T T1 P.8
16 ID16    B         T T2 P.8
```

Normally, without the repeated measures, I would do something like

```
mock$ttt <- with(mock, paste(type, treatment, tp, sep="_"))
mm <- model.matrix(~ 0 + ttt, mock)
```

...and then define contrasts `(B_T_T2-B_C_T2)-(B_T_T1-B_C_T1)` to test an interaction between time points and treatment within type B.

However, I am at loss how to do it with the repeated measures. I tried the following:

```
mock$type_pid <- paste0(mock$type, "_", mock$PID)
mm <- model.matrix(~ 0 + type_pid + type:tp:treatment, mock)
```

I get a matrix which is *not* fully ranked, however I have the coefficients I need for my contrasts. How can I get a fully ranked matrix with the necessary coefficients?

Please note that I am not trying to fit a mixed random model (despite the repeated measures), because my particular setup does not allow for this.

Comment: You can always guarantee full rank by appending a nonzero multiple of the identity matrix (or any other full-rank matrix of its dimensions) to the model matrix.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/164546/919 for details.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that it's not possible to tell (purely syntactically) from the formula that the matrix is not of full rank, so `model.matrix()` can't know this.

I think you either need to write a function that knows more about the structure of your experiment, or you need linear algebra: one possibility is to do

```
xqr<-qr(X)

qr.X(xqr, ncol=xqr$rank)
```