# On a Ridge regression-like problem

Tags: regression, machine-learning, least-squares, regularization, ridge-regression

I am trying to implement a sort of Ridge regression for the following problem
\begin{equation}
y = a^\top X b,
\end{equation}
where $y\in \mathbb{R}$, $a\in\mathbb{R}^M$, $b\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and $X\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ and $a^\top$ denotes the transpose matrix of $a$.

$X$ is a matrix which coefficients are unknown, and I aim to find them by minimizing the following Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
\min_{X} \Vert y - a^\top X b \Vert^2 + \beta \mbox{Tr}(XX^\top)
\end{equation}
where $\beta > 0$ is a standard Ridge regression parameter and $\mbox{Tr}$(·) is the trace operator.

I know the regression solution without the regularization term, since it can be easily calculated by means of the Moore-Penrose inverse:
\begin{equation}
X = (aa^\top)^{-1}ayb^\top(bb^\top)^{-1}
\end{equation}

However, I am unable to find either a closed expression for $X$ when the regularization term is included, or a proper numerical algorithm to calculate it.

Is there any reference that could shed some light on this? Thank you.

Comment: $aa^T$ has rank 1 and has no inverse. Similar for $b$.

Comment: This is standard least squares regression, merely written in a slightly different way.  So, write it out explicitly for (say) $M=N=2$ to see what's going on.  If you're familiar with vector manipulations, you might recognize that $a^\prime X b = \operatorname{Tr}(ab^\prime X).$

Comment: @gunes that is true, thank you. I have to rethink that part too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing the values for observation $i$ as $\mathbf{a}_i = (a_{i1},a_{i2},\ldots, a_{im}),$ $\mathbf{b}_i=(b_{i1},b_{i2},\ldots, b_{in})$, and $y_i$ ($i=1,2,\ldots, N$), this model can be expressed as

$$E[y_i] = \sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ij}X_{jk}b_{ik}  = \sum_l \alpha_{il} X_l $$

where $l$ indexes the $mn$ ordered pairs $(j,k)$ and $\alpha_{il} = a_{ij}b_{ik}.$ *This is a standard ordinary least squares (OLS) multiple regression problem.*  In statistical parlance, it consists of all the "interactions" between the $\mathbf{a}$ variables and $\mathbf{b}$ variables but has no constant or direct effects.  (See the subtitle to the upper left plot in the figure below for an example of the formula.)  The coefficient $X_{jk},$ to be estimated, is the interaction between component $j$ of the $\mathbf{a}$ variables and component $k$ of the $\mathbf{b}$ variables.

Moreover, although Ridge Regression is most efficiently carried out with a dedicated algorithm (to rapidly update the solutions as the relaxation parameter $\beta$ is varied), it can be executed with a standard OLS formula (as quoted in the question) after observing the Ridge Regression solution *is* the OLS solution with an [augmented design matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/164546/919).  This requires just two lines in the `R` code below: one to construct a formula to specify the model and the second to carry out the regression.

In tests, I find this approach to be effective primarily when $N/(mn)$ is not much greater than $1.$  Otherwise it is usually misleading, concerning both how many coefficients of $X$ to use and how to estimate them (it shrinks them too much).  Consider using the Lasso instead.

#### Example

I generated explanatory variables and coefficients independently with a standard Normal distribution, then added *iid* standard Normal noise to the computed values of the $y_i.$  I randomly zeroed out half the coefficients in $X.$

Here are ridge trace plots for two cases where $m=2,$ $n=3,$ and $N/(mn)$ is $1.5$ (top row) and $15$ (bottom row).  The true coefficients (components of $X$) are plotted along the vertical axis using red for true zeros and black otherwise.  (The red ticks are jittered to resolve their overlap.)

[image: Figure]

The regularization helps in the top row but seems less than useful in the bottom row.

---

Here is the (reproducible) `R` code used to implement the solution, run the simulation, and plot the results.

```
m <- 2
n <- 3
N <- ceiling(1.5*m*n)
sigma <- 1 # Error S.D.
p <- 1/2   # Fraction of true coefficients to be zero

set.seed(17)
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for (iter in 1:6) {
  #
  # Determine the number of observations and establish the range of 
  # coeffcients `beta` for the ridge regression.
  #
  if (iter > 3) N <- ceiling(15*m*n)  # Increase `N` for the bottom row
  beta=seq(0, N/(m*n), length.out=101)# Specify the ridge trace (search space)
  #
  # Generate a model `X` and data `a` and `b`.
  #
  i <- sample.int(n*m, floor(p*n*m))            # These coefficients will be zero
  X <- rnorm(m*n); X[i] <- 0; X <- matrix(X, m) # The coefficients
  a <- matrix(rnorm(m*N, m), N)                 # The `a` explanatory variables
  b <- matrix(rnorm(n*N, n), N)                 # The `b` explanatory variables
  #
  # Create a data frame that holds all the `a` and `b` variables.
  #
  df <- apply(cbind(a, b), 2, scale)
  colnames(df) <- c(anames <- paste0("a", seq_len(m)), 
                    bnames <- paste0("b", seq_len(n)))
  #
  # Compute the "true" response `y.0` and add noise for the observed response.
  #
  y.0 <-  sapply(seq_len(N), function(i) df[i, 1:m] %*% X %*% df[i, 1:n+m])
  df <- as.data.frame(cbind(df, y=y.0 + rnorm(N, 0, sigma)))
  ###################
  # Ridge regression.
  ###################
  library(MASS) # lm.ridge
  #
  # Specify the model.
  #
  f <- as.formula(paste0("y ~ (", paste(anames, collapse="+"), ")*(",
                         paste(bnames, collapse="+"), ") - (",
                         paste(c("1", anames, bnames), collapse="+"), ")"))
  #
  # Fit it using Ridge Regression.
  #
  fit <- lm.ridge(f, df, lambda=beta)
  # (That's it!) ####
  #
  # Plot the ridge trace.
  #
  # plot(fit, xlab=expression(beta), ylab="Coefficient", lwd=2) # Built-in ridge trace
  subtitle <- gsub(" ", "", ifelse(iter==1, paste0("y ~ ", as.character(f)[3], ""), ""))
  subtitle <- sub("-", " - ", subtitle)
  plot(range(fit$lambda), range(c(c(X), fit$coef)), bty="n", type="n",
       xlab=expression(beta), ylab="Coefficient",
       main=paste0("Ridge Trace for N=", N, " and mn=", m*n), cex.main=1.2)
  mtext(subtitle, line=0.25, cex=min(0.6, 5/(m+n+1)))
  with(fit, {
    invisible(sapply(seq_len(dim(coef)[1]), 
                     function(i) 
                       lines(lambda, coef[i,], lwd=2, lty=(1 + i%%6), 
                                     col=hsv(i/dim(coef)[1], .8, .7))))
  })
  #
  # Add the rug plot.
  #
  k <- sum(c(X)==0)
  rug(seq(-k, k, by=2)*0.01, col="Red", side=2)
  rug(c(X)[X != 0], side=2)
}
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is really enlightening. To be honest, I had never considered the possibility of introducing the LASSO term in the objective function, but I will definitely give it a try. However, I am a bit cautious regarding its performance, due to its tendency to force some of the regression coefficients to zero. Thanks again :)

Comment: The nice thing about framing this as a standard linear regression problem is that you now have available the whole panoply of techniques, including Ridge Regression, Lasso, Elastic Net, Bayesian methods, and so on.