# Centering vs standardizing in ridge regression

Tags: regression, standardization, ridge-regression

I have read that to apply ridge regression, we first need to standardize the predictive variables. That is because the variables should be in a homogenous scale so that lambda has an effect of the same magnitude on all of them.

However, taking a look at the ridge regression implementation of the scikit-learn library, I see that the X variables are centered but not standardized. That is, the variables retain their scale.

I was wondering if you know why that is, and when is each technique (standardization vs centering) advised.

Comment: The centering is probably to make life easier by orthogonalizing the variables against the intercept. For better or worse, it seems they're trusting the user to specify the right scales for ridge. In my view, you should basically always center and scale.

Comment: Hi John, I missed the first part of your comment. Could you expand on what you mean?

Comment: Related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201909/when-to-normalize-data-in-regression/202002#202002

Comment: @Paca there are little things that come up and bite your ankles if you're trying to write an algorithm and don't center your variables :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code is not necessarily the best way of learning such things. If you look at [this discussion at Scikit-learn's GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/16445) (and outgoing links) its developers decided to deprecate a misleading default argument, so instead users could explicitly scale the data, as they suggest, with [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), i.e. subtracting the mean and dividing by standard deviation. So what you see in the code is a bad design decision that is currently being reverted. You are applying the same penalty to all the variables, so if they have different scales the [penalty would impact them at different force](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519450/why-the-ridge-regression-is-not-scale-invariant).

Comment: Does that mean that the X variables should always be standardized? Is merely centering a bad idea?

Comment: @Paca yes, I edited for more explanation.