# interview question: ridge regression the out-of-sample performance never change when tune the hyperparameter?

Tags: regularization, ridge-regression

I happened to an interview question:

> In Ridge regression, what does it imply if the out-of-sample performance never change however we tune the hyperparameter (the coefficient of L2 regularization)?

I only know that there exists an optimal coefficient which makes the MSE of ridge smaller than its OLS estimation. I am not sure if it is related to this question and I have the no idea for the answer.

Comment: What is L2 regularization intended to accomplish?  Think, then, of what it can accomplish when that objective is unnecessary: namely, when all the explanatory variables already are orthogonal.

Comment: @whuber does that mean when the multicollinearity is not heavy, change of $\lambda$ cannot improve the performance (reduce MSE) significantly? Here mentioned the `out-of-sample`, why do we specially use this?

Comment: That is the heart of the question. It makes one wonder exactly what "out-of-sample performance" really means.  Exactly what observations constitute "out of sample"? Would it be referring to cross-validation?  Testing on a hold-out set?  Testing on new data altogether?  Once you have decided that, it would be possible to analyze the situation mathematically.  I find the approach described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/164546/919 to be particularly helpful at visualizing what might be going on.

Comment: @whuber many thanks. And could you also refer me some answers of "why ridge can reduce the multicollinearity"? Since up to now, I can only explain: `multicollinearity increases estimation variance -> ridge reduces variance -> therefore ridge reduces multicollinearity.` But actually this logic does not convince me strongly, It is better to have some detailed deduction.

Comment: @whuber very nice explanation of extended $n+p$ matrix. But i still don't understand "out-of-sample performance" here, could you open an answer here to discuss more details? Since recently I happened too many questions of ridge and multicollinearity.