# How does addition of a regularization term ensures that the matrix is nonsingular? ( least squares )

Tags: least-squares, regularization, pattern-recognition

In Bishop's Pattern recognition [book](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ewurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf), in 3.1.2 Geometry of least squares section (page 143, last paragraph of section), it is stated that:

> In practice, a direct solution of the normal equations can lead to
> numerical difficulties when ΦTΦ is close to singular. In particular,
> when two or more of the basis vectors ϕj are co-linear, or nearly so,
> the resulting parameter values can have large magnitudes. Such near
> degeneracies will not be uncommon when dealing with real data sets.
> The resulting numerical difficulties can be addressed using the
> technique of singular value decomposition, or SVD (Press et al., 1992;
> Bishop and Nabney, 2008). Note that the addition of a regularization
> term ensures that the matrix is nonsingular, even in the presence of
> degeneracies.

I did not understand how adding a regularization term can prevent Φ^TΦ matrix to be singular. This is just a sum (**λI+Φ^TΦ** instead of **Φ^TΦ** (I: identity matrix))

Particularly, this part is confusing me:

> Note that the addition of a regularization term ensures that the
> matrix is nonsingular, even in the presence of degeneracies.

Pdf of book is available here: [http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ewurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf)

Comment: Here's a sketch: Any $M=\Phi^T \Phi$ (for real $\Phi$) must be positive *semi*-definite (sums of squares must be non-negative). Adding $\lambda I$ (for $\lambda > 0$) guarantees that the singular values must be positive (sum of positive number and non-negative number must be positive). You can demonstrate this by writing down the SVD of $\Phi$ and working through the algebra of $M + \lambda I$.

Comment: @Sycorax That machinery is overkill.  In the context $A=\Phi^\prime T\Phi$ *must* be square and positive semi-definite. (Otherwise the conclusion is incorrect.)  Now, $\lambda+A$ is singular for a positive real number $\lambda$ if and only if there exists nonzero $x$ for which $(\lambda + A)x=0$ (that's the definition of "singular"). That's obviously equivalent to the eigenvalue equation $Ax=-\lambda x,$ yet we know (by supposition) that $A$ has no negative eigenvalues, *QED.*

Comment: @whuber That’s a much better demonstration!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69205/ is closely related: it discusses Ridge Regression, which is an example of this form of regularization.

Comment: How could I not think of that, of course, it makes sense! Thank you so much for your explanations @Sycorax

Comment: Thank you @whuber  for your comments and the url that you shared!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the formulation:

$$ \frac{1}{2} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} {\left\| x \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

The optimal solution is given by $ \hat{x} = {\left( {A}^{T} A + \lambda I \right)}^{-1} {A}^{T} b $.

Since $ {A}^{T} A $ is symmetric all of its eigenvectors are real.
It is also Positive Semi Definite, hence all its eigenvalues are non negative.
Hence for $ \lambda > 0 $ the matrix $ {A}^{T} A + \lambda I $ must have all positive eigenvalues which means it is invertible (Stable) since it is a Positive Definite Matrix.

Comment: The point is that "large enough" is *any positive value whatsoever.*  The information you are neglecting is that $A^\prime A$ obviously has no negative eigenvalues.

Answer (score 6):

This demonstration starts from the definition of positive (semi) definite. We can use the definition of the $L^2$ norm to show that the quadratic form must be non-negative.

$$
x^T \Phi^T \Phi x = \| \Phi x \|_2^2 \ge 0
$$

The intuition here is that the shortest length the vector $\Phi x$ can have is 0, which corresponds to standard understandings about *lengths*. Or, generically, we're considering the sums of squares (that's what the $L^2$ norm is) of real numbers, so it must be non-negative.

So now we know that $\Phi^T \Phi$ is positive *semi*-definite. To answer the question, we need to further show that $M = \Phi^T \Phi + \lambda I$ is nonsingular for $\lambda > 0$.

We can use the same strategy again:

$$\begin{align}
x^T \left( \Phi^T\Phi + \lambda I\right) x &= x^T \Phi^T\Phi x + \lambda x^T x \\
&= \| \Phi x \|_2^2  + \lambda \| x \|_2^2 \gt 0
\end{align}$$

We know that this quadratic form must be **positive** because the length of any nonzero vector $x$ is positive. The sum of a non-negative and a positive number is positive.

Therefore, the regularized matrix $M$ satisfies the definition of positive definite. A matrix that is positive definite has all positive eigenvalues, which means that 0 is not an eigenvalue. By the invertible matrix theorem, $M $ is nonsingular.

---

This demonstration shows why $M$ is nonsingular for **any** $\lambda >0$. In other words,  **the choice of $\lambda $ does not depend on $\Phi$**. We know that this is the case because we've shown that all eigenvalues of $\Phi^T \Phi $ are *non-negative,* which is more specific than showing that all eigenvalues are real.

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into linear algebra, the intuition is very simple, actually. The difference between $$(\Phi'\Phi+\lambda I)^{-1}\\(\Phi'\Phi)^{-1}$$ is like like the difference between $$\frac 1 {x^2+\lambda}\\\frac 1 {x^2}$$ where $x\in\mathbb R$: $$x^2\in[0,\infty)\\x^2+\lambda\in[\lambda,\infty)$$
Hence, the regularized version doesn't have a singularity at $x=0$ when $\lambda\gt 0$

Comment: you obviously have to do linear algebra, but the analogy, again, is simple: it corresponds to $\frac 1 {x^2+\lambda}$. When $\lambda>0$, there's no singularity.

Comment: By using suitable definitions we can avoid linear algebra altogether (or at least keep it at the high school level). For any square matrix $A$ (symmetric or not) if there is a number $\lambda\gt 0$ for which $A+\lambda$ is singular, then--by definition--there would exist a nonzero vector $x$ for which $(A+\lambda)x=0.$  Upon left-multiplying both sides by $x^\prime$ we would conclude $x^\prime Ax=-\lambda|x|^2\lt0.$ That is impossible, because in this context $x^\prime Ax$ represents a sum of squares, which cannot be negative.