# Elastic net can be seen as lasso

Tags: lasso, ridge-regression, elastic-net

Let $y \in \Bbb R^n$, $\Bbb 1$ be an n-vector with all its entries equal to $1$, and $Z \in \Bbb R^{n×p}$ with columns of
unit norm and such that $Z^T \Bbb 1 = 0$. The elastic net is a penalized regression procedure for fitting the model $y ∼ \mathcal N (\beta_0 \Bbb 1 + Z \xi, σ^2
I)$, combining both ridge regression and the lasso.
This is done by simultaneously including $L_2$ and $L_1$ terms in the penalty. Its minimization objective is given by
$$\min_{\beta_0 \in \Bbb R, \xi \in \Bbb R^p} \big\{ \lVert y-\beta_0 \Bbb 1 - Z \xi \rVert_2^2 + \lambda_2 \lVert \xi\rVert_2^2 + \lambda_1\lVert \xi\rVert_1 \big\} $$
Show that this objective function can be reformulated into a lasso-type one (i.e. into a
new penalized regression problem with new variables and only an $L_1$ penalty).

I thought of using Pythagore to join the two $L_2$ norms but I does not lead  anywhere since the vectors are not orthogonal. I also thought of dividing the whole expression by $\lVert \xi\rVert_2^2$, so that the problem would be the same but the radius relative to the $L_1$ norm would depend on $\xi$ and I don't think we want that. Can we even get a nice closed form for this problem ?

Comment: Setting $\lambda_2=0$ is exactly the lasso problem, but the solution to the lasso problem does not have a closed form.

Comment: We are not allowed $\lambda_2$ here, it is fixed

Comment: My [characterization of Ridge Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/164546/919) gives a full answer because it shows explicitly how the quadratic part of this objective can be seen as an OLS objective.