# Quadratic Programming for ridge regression

Tags: r, regression, optimization, ridge-regression

I'm trying to use either `pracma::quadprog` or `quadprog::solve.QP` in R to solve a ridge regression, which can be written as a constrained optimization:
$$\begin{aligned}
minimize \ \frac12|| y - X \beta||_2^2 \\
s.t. ||\beta||_2^2 \leq t
\end{aligned}$$

While both functions can solve
$$\begin{aligned}
minimize \ \frac12x^TQx+d^Tx \\
s.t. Ax \leq b
\end{aligned}$$

I think I can let $Q = X^TX$, $d = y^TX$, the objective of ridge regression could be used in either function. But I'm wondering how I could transform $||\beta||_2^2 \leq t$ to $Ax \leq b$ as the former is quadratic?

Comment: Consider asking this on a site about numerical computing, because using quadratic programming for this problem would be unusual and inefficient, since [any least squares solution method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/164546/919) works.